# Solving $\left(\;1-a\cos(\theta-\alpha)\;\right)\left(\;1-b\cos(\theta-\beta)\;\right)=\frac14\left(1-a^2\right)\left(1-b^2\right)$ for $\theta$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $0\lt a, b\lt 1$ be two constants.
Then, how can I solve the trig equation 
$$\left(\;1-a\cos(\theta-\alpha)\;\right)\left(\;1-b\cos(\theta-\beta)\;\right)=\frac14\left(1-a^2\right)\left(1-b^2\right)$$ for $\theta$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$?

Comment: Please begin by showing your work.Find the constant, note the symmetries.

Comment: Hint: use the complex definition of the cosine, $(z+z^{-1})/2$, where $z=e^{i\theta}$. This should lead you to a polynomial equation of the fourth degree.

Comment: @Narasimham: I got this equation when I solve a question relating to projectiles. I do not know a way to start to solve this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Nice suggestion. But how can I solve a 4th degree equation? For me it is difficult than this equation.

Comment: @Nil: it may turn out that there is an obvious root or a special property; otherwise there are closed formulas for the quartics. You probably can't escape the complexity.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thank you. I will try this and if I got a something useful I will show.

Comment: Can we know how you got it,  may be two angles of firing between two (same ) start and target points?

Comment: @Nil: given that the expression has four independent coefficients, I strongly suspect that no simplification is possible (except for some particular values of the parameter) and this is a general case of a quartic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [angle difference formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) to establish

$$\cos(\theta-\alpha)=\cos\theta\cos\alpha+\sin\theta\sin\alpha$$

Use the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to write

$$\cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\qquad\sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

Then you have

$$
\tfrac14\left(1-a^2\right)\left(1-b^2\right)=
\left\{1-a\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\cos\alpha+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\sin\alpha\right)\right\}\left\{1-b\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\cos\beta+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\sin\beta\right)\right\}
$$

Multiply by $1+t^2$ to get

$$\tfrac14(1+t^2)\left(1-a^2\right)\left(1-b^2\right)=
\left\{1+t^2-a\left((1-t^2)\cos\alpha+2t\sin\alpha\right)\right\}\left\{1+t^2-b\left((1-t^2)\cos\beta+2t\sin\beta\right)\right\}$$

This is a [quartic (i.e. degree $4$) polynomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) in $t$, which may or may not simplify in some way. [Solve it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), then reverse the tangent half-angle substitution using $\theta=2\arctan t$. If the degree of your equation should happen to be less than four, be aware of the fact that the tangent half-angle substitution associates $\theta=\pm180°$ with $t=\infty$, so check whether that's a solution as well.